# Finding all nice ideals for quiver algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, computer-algebra, gap

Let $Q$ be a finite, connected and acyclic quiver which is simply-laced.
Let $k$ be a field and $kQ$ the path algebra of $Q$ over $k$.
Recall that an ideal $I$ of $kQ$ is called admissible if it is generated by linear combininations of paths of length at least two.
We call an ideal $I$ nice if it is admissible and the field coefficients appearing in the linear combinatations are just 1 or -1. Call two nice ideals $I_1$ and $I_2$ isomorphic if $kQ/I_1$ and $kQ/I_2$ are isomorphic $k$-algebras.

> Question 1: Are there combinatorial methods to count the number of nice ideals for a given $Q$ (up to isomorphism or not)?

For example when $Q$ is a linear oriented line with $n$ points, the number of nice ideals is given by the Catalan nubmer $C_{n-1}$. What are the number of nice ideals up to isomorphism for example when we choose $Q_n$ to be the quiver of the incidence algebra of the Boolean lattice of an $n$-set?

> Question 2: Is there a way to obtain all nice (quadratic) ideals for a given quiver $Q$ using QPA or another computer algebra system?

There might be too many so it does not work for larger $Q$, so maybe one can restrict to quadratic nice ideals.